# Clicking browser back button gives a error message "Confirm form resubmission" in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I know there are similar kind of questions posted on this site. But I have different issue. Please look at the below description once. I have already looked in all the answers, but did not get any useful from that.

I have a 'View' say View1, where a Search form is available. In the controller named 'Home' , there are 2 functions named as 'find' and 'advsearch' which direct to 'View1' only.

1. Suppose currently we enter 'home/find' in URL, 'View1' is displayed.
2. If I submit 'Search Form' which is on View1, form will direct to 'home/advsearch' and the result is displayed on the same view 'View1'.
3. If I click back button of browser, it again goes to url 'home/find' and display 'View1'. Which is expected and working fine.

Issue: Submit 'Search form' multiple times, It keep showing the searched result on View1. But when we click the back button of browser. It shows URL 'home/advsearch' but throws error message "Confirm form resubmission".

How can it be handled, so on clicking back button, It should display data but not that resubmission error message?

Comment: Why not submiting your form in ajax if you're using the same view ?

Comment: Hi Adrien, Thanks for suggestion..I tried as you suggested..But the data which  I am getting through ajax ,is not passing to the controller..I have checked the data in console logs..It is coming properly after submit ..Please find my ajax code below and let me know if I am doing something wrong..I tried to take the data in controller wit $this->input->Post(something);

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var alllocation = $("#all_location").val();                                                                                                       
            var experience = $('#exp').val();
            var skills = $('#allskills').val();
            var posted_by = $('#postedby').val();

Comment: var post_data = {
              'all_locations': all_location,
              'exp':experience,
              'allskills':skills,
              'postedby':posted_by
            };
            $.post('<?php //echo site_url('job/find');?>',post_data,function(data){
                $('.main_container').html(post_data);
            });
        });
    });
    
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem and foud out the easiest solution. most probably the right way to handle search requests. Just change the search form's method to GET and pass the keywords in url.

to recieve the form data:

> $this->input->get('input_name');